# What is the asymptotics of: $\Re\left(\frac{\zeta \left(1+\frac{1}{c}\right) \zeta (s+i t)}{\zeta \left(s+i t+\frac{1}{c}+1-1\right)}\right)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, asymptotics, riemann-zeta, theta-functions

> What is the asymptotics of the function $f(s,t,c)$:
> $$f(s,t,c)=\Re\left(\frac{\zeta \left(1+\frac{1}{c}\right) \zeta (s+i t)}{\zeta \left(s+i t+\frac{1}{c}+1-1\right)}\right)$$
> ?

For $c=10^4$ the plot of the function in the complex plane is:

[image: complex plane plot]

```
(*Mathematica start*)
c = 10^4;
Plot3D[Re[
  Zeta[s + I t]*Zeta[1 + 1/c]/Zeta[s + I t + 1 + 1/c - 1]], {s, -60, 
  60}, {t, -60, 60}]
(*end*)
```

On the critical line $s=1/2$ the asymptotics appears to be:

$$\Re\left(\frac{\zeta \left(1+\frac{1}{c}\right) \zeta \left(\frac{1}{2}+i t\right)}{\zeta \left(\frac{1}{2}+i t+\frac{1}{c}+1-1\right)}\right) \sim c+\frac{\partial \vartheta (t)}{\partial t}+\gamma$$

where $\vartheta (t)$ is the Riemann-Siegel Theta function.

[image: On the critical line]

```
(*Mathematica start*)
Clear[n, k, t, A, nn];
f[t_] = D[RiemannSiegelTheta[t], t];
nnn = 60
c = 10^1;
g1 = Plot[(f[t] + c + EulerGamma), {t, 0, nnn}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.004], Red}, PlotRange -> {0, c + 5}];
g2 = Plot[
   Re[Zeta[1/2 + I*t]*
     Zeta[1 + 1/c]/Zeta[1/2 + I*t + 1 + 1/c - 1]], {t, 0, nnn}, 
   PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.02], PlotRange -> {0, c + 5}];
Show[g2, g1, ImageSize -> Large]
(*end*)
```

Comment: Try setting the denominator to not be equal to 0. This may not be solvable unless you can transform the zeta function into another form where you can solve for t or c. Also, wouldn’t the “+1-1” be just 0?

Comment: Writing $+1-1$ comes from the Dirichlet generating function that I am interested in: $-\frac{\zeta '(s)}{\zeta (s)}=\lim_{c\to 1} \, \left(\frac{\zeta (c) \zeta (s)}{\zeta (c+s-1)}-\zeta (c)\right)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for the critical line, the general case may be treated in a similar manner. By Taylor expanding about $c=\infty$, we find
$$
\zeta \!\left( {1 + \frac{1}{c}} \right) = c + \gamma  + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{c}} \right)
$$
and
$$
\zeta \!\left( {\frac{1}{2} + it + \frac{1}{c}} \right) = \zeta\! \left( {\frac{1}{2} + it} \right) + \zeta '\!\left( {\frac{1}{2} + it} \right)\frac{1}{c} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{c^2 }}} \right).
$$
This gives
$$
\frac{{\zeta\! \left( {1 + \frac{1}{c}} \right)\zeta\! \left( {\frac{1}{2} + it} \right)}}{{\zeta\! \left( {\frac{1}{2} + it + \frac{1}{c}} \right)}} = c - \frac{{\zeta '\!\left( {\frac{1}{2} + it} \right)}}{{\zeta \!\left( {\frac{1}{2} + it} \right)}} + \gamma  + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{c}} \right).
$$
Since
$$
 - \frac{{\zeta '\!\left( {\frac{1}{2} + it} \right)}}{{\zeta\! \left( {\frac{1}{2} + it} \right)}} = \frac{{d\vartheta (t)}}{{dt}} + i\frac{{Z'(t)}}{{Z(t)}},
$$
we find
$$
\Re \frac{{\zeta\! \left( {1 + \frac{1}{c}} \right)\zeta\! \left( {\frac{1}{2} + it} \right)}}{{\zeta\! \left( {\frac{1}{2} + it + \frac{1}{c}} \right)}} = c + \frac{{d\vartheta (t)}}{{dt}} + \gamma  + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{c}} \right).
$$

Comment: Before your answer I expanded the wrong variable. And also, I was not aware of the identity: $- \frac{{\zeta '\!\left( {\frac{1}{2} + it} \right)}}{{\zeta\! \left( {\frac{1}{2} + it} \right)}} = \frac{{d\vartheta (t)}}{{dt}} + i\frac{{Z'(t)}}{{Z(t)}},$

Comment: The identity is coming from the logarithmic derivative of $$
\zeta \left( {\tfrac{1}{2} + it} \right) = Z(t)e^{i\vartheta (t)} .
$$